# Oracle Pl/SQL: Trigger after insert on Table1 calling a function for Table2?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm rather new to Oracle PL/SQL, so I'm not sure whether it's possible to do something like this:

Two tables - T1 and T2 - T1.id is foreign key referencing T2.id, each table has a sequence;
I've written a function that when it's called allows the user to insert new rows in T1 - will call it func1, same for T2 - func2;
Also a function that get us the last inserted sequence in a table - getLastSeq(table);

So, now I'm trying to create a trigger after insert on T2 calls func1, allowing the user to write the input info.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER INSERT ON T2
DECLARE
-----?----
BEGIN
----?----
dbms_output.put_line(func1(:col1, :col2));
----?----?
END;
```

But all my possible attempts to do so die with errors about :col1 not being a bad bind var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

1. If you are creating a PL/SQL block that inserts a row, that really ought to be a procedure, not a function.  A function is supposed to perform a computation and return a result.  A procedure is supposed to do DML.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by "allowing the user to write the input info".  PL/SQL has no facilities to prompt the user for input-- it can only accept input parameters.
3. I'm not sure that I understand how an insert into a parent table (`T2`) could ever logically insert a row into a child table (`T1`).  That would imply that `T1` is not really a child table which implies that you have some sort of problem with the data model.

If your goal is to pass the newly inserted `COL1` and `COL2` tables from the row that was just inserted into `T2` to the `PROC1` procedure, my guess is that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_t2
  AFTER INSERT ON t2
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  proc1( :new.col1, :new.col2 );
END;
```

It sounds, though, like you may not want to use a trigger at all.  If you want to create an order, you'd normally have a procedure that executes multiple `INSERT` statements rather than trying to insert into the child table from a trigger on the parent.  Something like this, for example, is going to be much clearer and much easier to maintain than a trigger-based solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_order( p_order_description IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO order( order_id, description )
    VALUES( order_id_seq.nextval, p_order_description );

  INSERT INTO order_ship_status( order_ship_status_id, order_id, status )
    VALUES( order_ship_status_id.nextval, order_id_seq.currval, 'Not Shipped' );
END:
```

Comment: I'll try to explain: I have two tables. When I insert new information in one of the tables, using a proceudre, I need to insert information in the other table, using another procedure. For example - we insert a new Order, and after I've inserted the data about it, I need to insert some additional information that is held in another table, that also gets information from other tables.

About the user input(I didn't word this correctly), I meant calling the procedure with bind variables.

Comment: @Izumi - Normally, if you're inserting data into a second table, you'd just make two `INSERT` calls in the procedure.

Comment: normally - yes, I was just trying to come up with some more interesting triggers, that's why I thought of having two procedures, and after one of it is done, it activates a trigger which calls the other procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You have your trigger syntax all wrong.

Read through this link which will give you a better understanding of Oracle triggers and some good examples you can follow.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm